# Data is null from Firestore when only Fetching (read), Provider

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-provider

I am facing the Issue, The result only show's "Empty" in the UI, I can't figure out the solution. I am using Provider as Statemangment. Firebase as backend.

I am only performing a simple action of just fetching the data.

here is the service code

```
Stream<List<CategoryModel>> getCateogoriesFromFirebase() {
  final categoryCollection =
      fireStoreInstance.collection('categories').snapshots();

  return categoryCollection.map((querySnapshots) {
    var categories = <CategoryModel>[];

    for (var singleCate in querySnapshots.docs) {
      CategoryModel categoryModel = CategoryModel.fromFirebase(singleCate);

      categories.add(categoryModel);
    }

    return categories;
  });
}
```

here is the controller part code

```
Stream<List<CategoryModel>> getCategoriesFiresotre() {
  return _dataBaseService.getCateogoriesFromFirebase();
}
```

here is the view code

```
SizedBox(

  height: 72,
  child: StreamBuilder(
      stream: Provider.of<HomeController>(
        context,
      ).getCategoriesFiresotre(),
      builder: (context, snapsshot) {
        if (snapsshot.data?.length == 0) {
          return Text('empty');
        }

        if (snapsshot.data != null) {
          return ListView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              itemCount: snapsshot.data?.length,
              itemBuilder: (c, i) {
                return Container(
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                  height: 50,
                  width: 100,
                  color: Colors.blueGrey,
                  child: Center(
                    child: Text(
                        snapsshot.data?[i].category ?? 'Category'),
                  ),
                );
              });
        }
        return CircularProgressIndicator();
      }),
),
```

The output, In the UI is only the `Text` widget "Empty"
I have checked the Firestore rules, They are all up to date.
[image]

Comment: The code looks fine at first glance, so it might be good to debug it locally. If you set a breakpoint on `return categoryCollection...` and run in the debugger, does it reach that line? If so, check that the value of `categoryCollection.docs` is. If there are no documents there, the problem is on the code that loads from the database. If there *are* documents, the problem is on the side that renders the documents.

Comment: The debugger stops at return categoryCollection and there  are no documents to be seen. and when the debugger itself stops at controller code Stream<List<CategoryModel>> getCategoriesFiresotre() {
  return _dataBaseService.getCateogoriesFromFirebase();
}. There are documents to be seen. Please note that I haven't used the "debugger" before

Comment: Oops, yeah I forgot how streams work for a moment there. Set the breakpoint on `for (var singleCate in querySnapshots.docs) {` and check `querySnapshots.docs.length`. If that is not 0, step through the loop and see if it does what you expect it to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My older Brother fixed the Problem. He was able to figure out the problem, which wasn't in the code rather than inside `Firestore`. I miss typed and wrote `categories`  instead of `categories`. I gave an extra space at the end causing the issue. Good luck Coding devs.